# Can't figure out how sum(1) is working in this query

Tags: sql-server, sum, aggregate-functions

So I am trying to combine to query's and to do that I need to figure out what is going on in this one. I'm still relatively new to sql server and I am forced to dive right into some complicated qrys and sometimes I get stuck on simple things like this. My problem is that the Sum(1) function is used and I'm not entirely sure how. Meaning I believe it is counting duplicates but I cannot tell based on what information it is doing so.

this is the query

```
SELECT 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.POLICY_NO, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.PHASE_CODE, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.SUB_PHASE_CODE, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.ProdType, 
TotalDPA = Sum(case when [SumOfNetDefExtraAdj] Is Null then [SumOfNetDefPremiumAdj] else [SumOfNetDefPremiumAdj] + SumOfNetDefExtraAdj end), 
Sum(1) AS Expr1
FROM qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re RIGHT JOIN qryReinsuranceDPA1
ON 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.POLICY_NO = qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.POLICY_NO AND 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.PHASE_CODE= qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.PHASE_CODE AND 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.SUB_PHASE_CODE = qryPolicyListforNYDefPRemAsset_Re.SUB_PHASE_CODE 
GROUP BY qryReinsuranceDPA1.POLICY_NO, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.PHASE_CODE, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.SUB_PHASE_CODE, 
qryReinsuranceDPA1.ProdType
--HAVING (((Sum(1))<>1))

GO
```

And this is a small sample of what it produces (the actually results number around 77,000)

```
POLICY_NO    PHASE_CODE    SUB_PHASE_CODE    ProdType   TotalDPA       Expr1
228433800    0             1                 TERM       282.324223     1
228439200    0             1                 PERM       53.17048634    1
228439200    6             1                 PERM       10.3805065     1
228441500    0             1                 PERM       526.6883742    1
228441500    0             2                 PERM       10.63320899    1
228441700    0             1                 PERM       20.86247317    1
228448100    0             1                 PERM       345.2117169    1
228460200    0             1                 TERM       302.7574933    1
228464900    0             1                 TERM       191.2597906    1
228468000    0             1                 PERM       8445.190912    1
228473600    0             1                 TERM       339.8413682    **2**
228473800    0             1                 TERM       686.1766864    **2**
228477200    0             1                 TERM       583.7580207    1
228481200    0             1                 TERM       362.9472595    1
228481200    0             2                 PERM       4.217792443    1
228482500    0             1                 PERM       1894.303507    1
228482500    1             1                 TERM       1312.183889    1
228491600    0             1                 TERM       325.0796843    **2**
228494400    0             1                 PERM       748.2710255    1
228501000    0             1                 TERM       47.78070676    1
228501100    0             1                 TERM       47.78070676    1
228501300    0             1                 PERM       365.5651862    1
228501300    0             2                 PERM       12.20547324    1
228501300    1             1                 TERM       706.0961491    1
228501300    1             2                 PERM       12.46769547    1
228502000    0             1                 PERM       6562.164879    1
228502000    0             2                 PERM       184.7741277    1
```

The right most column is the result of the Sum(1) and what I want to know is when and why does it produce a 2.

Comment: thank you for editing it i couldn't figure out how to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sum(1)` is exactly equivalent to `count(*)` - it returns a count of all the rows within the group.

It will therefore return a value of 2 when, for a given value for each of POLICY_NO, PHASE_CODE, SUB_PHASE_CODE and ProdType there are two rows in the selected dataset (before grouping).

Comment: Yes, but when you say "Sum(1) will provide the count" it sounds like part of a "Who's on first?" IT routine.

Comment: @HABO: Errm, what? I didn't say "Sum(1) will provide the count" and I don't know what a "Who's on first?" IT routine is.

Comment: SUM(1) = "someone"   SUM(1) forgot about COUNT(*).